# C++ Counting character occurrence from a text file regardless of case

Tags: c++

In C++, I am trying to take text from a file and count the occurrences of characters, ignoring differences in case. So far, I can do this without ignoring case.

```
map<char, size_t> char_count;
char character;
while (myfile >> character)
    ++char_count[character];   // fetch and increment the counter for word
for (const auto &w : char_count) // for each element in the map
    // print the results
    cout <<  w.first << " occurs " << w.second
         << ((w.second > 1) ? " times" : " time") << endl;
```

My solution for this was going to be:

```
character = tolower(character)
```

but `tolower()` will not take a char, only an int. Any ideas? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: A `char` will be promoted to an `int` when you call `tolower`. It will be fine to use `tolower(character)`.

Comment: my output when doing this is: " occurs 1 time and it ignores all other characters in the file

Comment: In that case, the problem lies elsewhere. See it working at https://ideone.com/EoMInO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's true, you can use `tolower` to convert a character to lowercase, i've modified your code, i hope it can help you :

```
while (myfile >> character)
    ++char_count[tolower(character)];
```

Comment: what is `size_t` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is applicable.
Just use `tolower` and convert the char to an int.

Comment: my output when doing this is: '" occurs 1 time' and it ignores all other characters in the file